# iTunes can't see copy of iPhone backup from external drive

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

I have an iTunes backup of an old iPhone on an external drive (My Passport portable HDD), where it was placed when it was recovered by a data recovery company. When I try to restore the backup to my new iPhone using iTunes on my PC, the "Restore Backup" button is faded out and unclickable. This is the case even after pasting a copy of the backup into the appropriate backup folder. iTunes is up to date. This is my process for trying to restore the backup to my new phone:

1. Erase all data from phone and restart setup
2. Go through setup until I reach the option to restore from PC and am prompted to plug into a laptop with iTunes
3. Plug into my laptop, enter security code
4. Pull up my iPhone in iTunes
5. Find "Restore Backup" button is unclickable

I tried creating a backup from the new phone and restoring that to it, and it worked just fine. I then deleted the contents of that new backup and replaced them with the contents of the backup I want, which got iTunes to finally at least find the right backup (since it had already "seen" it). When I tried to restore the Frankenstein backup, it appeared to work for a while but eventually failed.

I've googled this, youtubed it, talked to two regular Apple support people and three specialists, talked to the Geek Squad, talked to an independent iPhone repair guy, and talked to someone from the company that did my data recovery. Apparently no one knows how to fix it. The opinions I got were:

- I don't know
- I don't know, but iTunes is finicky about backups being moved/in the wrong place
- I don't know, and I also can't touch it for liability reasons
- It's probably corrupted - sending iPhone backups on regular drives not made for iPhone risks this (data recovery company disputed this)

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Failing that, does anyone at least know what might be causing it?

Please ask if you need more information. I truly know nothing about this and might be leaving out something important.